# What happend will subClass and SuperClass have same attributes in Java?

Tags: java

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.test();
    }

}

class A {
    String aString = "a";
    
    void test() {
        System.out.println(aString);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    String aString = "b";
}
```

why the cant input out "b"?
i just think `b.test()` will call method of superClass, so b will user superClass's attribute.

Comment: Fields _aren't_ overridden like methods.

Answer (score 4):

> why the cant input out "b"? i just think `b.test()` will call method of superClass, so b will user superClass's attribute.

Java class and instance variables can be inherited, but they are not virtual.  That is, all variable identifiers appearing in Java code are resolved at compile time -- there is no dynamic resolution for them.

Thus, the appearance of identifier `aString` in method `A.test()` is resolved at compile time to the `aString` attribute of class `A`.  This is the attribute that all invocations of that method will access, regardless of the actual class of the object on which it is invoked.  If you want to use the attribute of class B when `test()` is invoked on an instance of that class then provide getter methods in classes `A` and `B` and have `A.test()` obtain the string via those.

Answer (score 1):

The variable in b is hiding the variable in a. You can fix it by removing the type in b

```
class B extends A {
    public B () {
      aString = "b";
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a syntax error to me. You'd have to put this assignment in the constructor, unless there is a feature of some recent version of Java I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> class A {
>     String aString = "a";
>     
>     void test() {
>         System.out.println(aString);
>     }
> }
>
> class B extends A {
>     String aString = "b";
> }
> ```

Creates 2 `aString` variables for B. While `A` will not know about `B` extending it, `B` can always access "things" from its parent class `A`, using the `super` keyword. So when you are in `B`, you can use `aString` and `super.aString` and they will refer the 2 different variables:

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        a.test();
        b.test();
        b.suptest();
    }
    
    static class A {
        String aString="A.aString set from A";
        void test() {
            System.out.println("A.test(): "+aString);
        }
    }
    static class B extends A {
        String aString="B.aString set from B";
        {
            super.aString="A.aString set from B";
        }
        void test() {
            System.out.println("B.test(): "+aString);
        }
        void suptest() {
            System.out.print("B.suptest() calling super.test(): ");
            super.test();
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/zKzDJa), produces output

> ```
> A.test(): A.aString set from A
> B.test(): B.aString set from B
> B.suptest() calling super.test(): A.test(): A.aString set from B
> ```

Where the first two lines show nothing fancy, `A.aString` and `B.aString` both contain their initial value.
But the third output line shows that `super.test()` call in `B` really "ends" in `A.test()`, and that the initializer block in `B` really altered the inherited `aString` field.

(Side note: the `static class` magic relates to the example being contained in a single file, it doesn't affect the inheritance-part)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Since `Class A` and the method `test()` are not abstract and the fact that the method `test()` was not overrided by its `subClass B`, the return will be exactly how was specified in `Class A` even if you call it from a `B` instance.

Comment: It doesn't matter if class `A` is abstract or not.

Comment: @saka1029 Yeah, I made a mistake. I was thinking about the method "test()" as abstract as well for this forces to implement the method in subclass.